# Why does the following Pattern not work for all OS versions?

Tags: android, regex, regular-language

Having the following regex tested on https://regex101.com/r/Q6lTN8/1

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<name>\\b\\w+\\b)\\s*=\\s*(?<value>\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'+)");
```

with this input text

```
id='1019' name='Beer' color='#e7c705'
```

Works well on Android versions > 6.0, but produces the following crash on Android 5.1

```
 Process: pro.kleinod.socialapp, PID: 19517

          java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 4:
                                                                    (?<name>\b\w+\b)\s*=\s*(?<value>"[^"]*"|'[^']*'+)
```

**What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture groups using `.*?` instead of with `<name>` or `<value>`, This way, you will avoid `PatternSyntaxException`:

```
String regex = "(.*?\\b\\w+\\b)\\s*=\\s*(.*?\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("id='1019' name='Beer' color='#e7c705'");
while(matcher.find()) {
    Log.e("TAG", matcher.group());
}
```

Tested and working fine on Android 5.1.